# Create multiple rows for results in multiple days

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I have a simple query to return all lines in a planning file that have not yet ended.

```
SELECT [Run_ID]
      ,[ProductionLineID]
      ,[RecipeNR]
      ,[RecipeDesc]
      ,[StartTimeBakery]
      ,[EndTimeBakery]
      ,[ItemID]
      ,[ItemDesc]
      ,[Boxes]
      ,[Products_In_Box]
      ,[Products]
      ,[Pallets]
      ,[Boxes_On_Pallet]
      ,[AUD_Timestamp]
  FROM [PP_Planning].[dbo].[Planning]

  Where endTimeBakery > GETDATE()

  order by ProductionLineID, StartTimeBakery
```

**Simplified sample result:**

```
StartTimeBakery           EndTimeBakery             Pallets
2018-10-12 03:00:00.000   2018-10-12 21:41:00.000   135
2018-10-12 22:00:00.000   2018-10-13 22:13:00.000   300
2018-10-13 23:59:00.000   2018-10-15 05:23:00.000   315
```

What I'm looking for is an automatic split when starttime-endtime spans more than a single day.

**Wanted output:**

```
StartTimeBakery           EndTimeBakery             Pallets
2018-10-12 03:00:00.000   2018-10-12 21:41:00.000   135,00
2018-10-12 22:00:00.000   2018-10-12 23:59:59.999   24,77
2018-10-13 00:00:00.000   2018-10-13 22:13:00.000   275,22
2018-10-13 23:59:00.000   2018-10-13 23:59:59.999   0,18
2018-10-14 00:00:00.000   2018-10-14 23:59:59.999   257,14
2018-10-15 00:00:00.000   2018-10-15 05:23:00.000   57,68
```

**Reasoning/logic**
I want to be able to show the amount of pallets produced(planned) per day. In the above wanted result I have taken the original total amount and divided it by time used between start and stop and used that to allocate to the time planned per day.

I don't know where to start to 'split' this. So any help is appreciated.

Comment: is the 'split' limited to being over two days?

Comment: As soon as it is multiple days, (2 to x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If date ranges are unspecified, you can use recursion to split source and get values required to calculate proportions. See following demo:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (StartTimeBakery DATETIME2(3), EndTimeBakery DATETIME2(3), Pallets INT);
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('2018-10-12 03:00:00.000','2018-10-12 21:41:00.000',135);
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('2018-10-12 22:00:00.000','2018-10-13 22:13:00.000',300);
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('2018-10-13 23:59:00.000','2018-10-15 05:23:00.000',315);

WITH Split AS
(
    SELECT *, 0 N, DATEDIFF(DAY, StartTimeBakery, EndTimeBakery) Diff FROM @table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT StartTimeBakery,EndTimeBakery,Pallets,N+1,Diff FROM Split WHERE N<Diff
), SplitDates AS
(
    SELECT
        StartTimeBakery,
        EndTimeBakery,
        Pallets,
        CASE WHEN N=0 THEN StartTimeBakery ELSE DATEADD(DAY,N, CAST(StartTimeBakery AS Date)) END MyStart,
        CASE WHEN N=Diff THEN EndTimeBakery ELSE DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -1, CAST(DATEADD(DAY,N+1, CAST(StartTimeBakery AS Date)) AS datetime2(3))) END MyEnd,
        N,
        Diff
    FROM Split
), Proportions AS
(
    SELECT *, DATEDIFF(millisecond, MyStart, MyEnd) ThisMs, SUM(DATEDIFF(millisecond, MyStart, MyEnd)) OVER (PARTITION BY StartTimeBakery) GroupMs
    FROM SplitDates
)
SELECT MyStart StartTimeBakery, MyEnd EndTimeBakery, CAST(1.0*Pallets*ThisMs/GroupMs as decimal(15,2)) Pallets
FROM Proportions
ORDER BY MyStart
```

**Results**

```
StartTimeBakery             EndTimeBakery               Pallets
--------------------------- --------------------------- ---------
2018-10-12 03:00:00.000     2018-10-12 21:41:00.000     135.00
2018-10-12 22:00:00.000     2018-10-12 23:59:59.999     24.78
2018-10-13 00:00:00.000     2018-10-13 22:13:00.000     275.22
2018-10-13 23:59:00.000     2018-10-13 23:59:59.999     0.18
2018-10-14 00:00:00.000     2018-10-14 23:59:59.999     257.14
2018-10-15 00:00:00.000     2018-10-15 05:23:00.000     57.68
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done via a recursive CTE

Example snippet:

```
declare @Table table (
 RunID int identity(1,1) primary key, 
 StartTimeBakery datetime, 
 EndTimeBakery datetime, 
 Pallets int
);

insert into @Table (StartTimeBakery, EndTimeBakery, Pallets) values
 (DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,-1, GETDATE()),'03:00'), DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,-1, GETDATE()),'21:41'), 135)
,(DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,-1, GETDATE()),'22:00'), DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,-2, GETDATE()),'22:13'), 300)
,(DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,-2, GETDATE()),'23:59'), DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,-4, GETDATE()),'05:23'), 315)
;


with RCTE as
(
    select 
    RunID, 
    StartTimeBakery as BaseStartTime, EndTimeBakery as BaseEndTime, Pallets as BasePallets,
    0 as Lvl, 
    StartTimeBakery as StartTime, 
    case 
    when cast(StartTimeBakery as date) =  cast(EndTimeBakery as date)
    then EndTimeBakery 
    else CONVERT(DATETIME,DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -10, DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(DATETIME2,CONVERT(DATE, StartTimeBakery))))) 
    end as EndTime, 
    Pallets
    from @Table
    where EndTimeBakery > GETDATE()

    union all

    select RunID, BaseStartTime, BaseEndTime, BasePallets,
    Lvl+1,
    CONVERT(DATETIME, DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(DATE,EndTime))),
    case when DATEADD(DAY, 1, EndTime) < BaseEndTime then DATEADD(DAY, 1, EndTime) else BaseEndTime end,
    Pallets
    from RCTE
    where EndTime < BaseEndTime
)
select 
StartTime AS StartTimeBakery,
EndTime AS EndTimeBakery,
CAST(Pallets * (CAST(DATEDIFF(second, StartTime, EndTime) AS FLOAT) / DATEDIFF(second, BaseStartTime, BaseEndTime)) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) as PercDiffMinutes
from RCTE
order by BaseStartTime, StartTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

for only one split (e.g max runover to next day, you could try something like

```
WITH FORE as 
    (
    Select *, 
           StartTimeBakery StartTime1, 
           CASE WHEN CAST(EndTimeBakery as date) = CAST(StartTimeBakery as date) THEN 
                   EndTimeBakery 
                ELSE DATEADD(ms,-1,CAST(CAST(EndTimeBakery as date) 
                                                     as datetime)) END AS EndTime1
    ),
    AFTER as
    (
    Select *, 
          CAST(CAST(EndTimeBakery as date) as datetime) StartTime1,
          EndTimeBakery EndTime1  
                    WHERE CAST(EndTimeBakery as date) = CAST(StartTimeBakery as date)
    ),
    SPLITS AS 
    (
            SELECT * FROM FORE 
              UNION ALL 
               SELECT * FROM AFTER
    )

    SELECT * FROM SPLITS;
```

so to explain, select all of the shift starts, with ends limited to the end of day (or earlier if shift ended by then)
then secondly select the set of records running over midnight, with start at 00:00, and end at ending time, then union them together.

How you choose to split other factors between these, you'd need to work that out

Answer (score 0):

Something quickly build, not too fancy sql but it works.

```
    DECLARE @table TABLE (StartTime DATETIME, EndTime DATETIME, Qty INT)

INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('2018-10-12 03:00:00.000','2018-10-12 21:41:00.000',135)
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('2018-10-12 22:00:00.000','2018-10-13 22:13:00.000',300)
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('2018-10-13 23:59:00.000','2018-10-15 05:23:00.000',315)

SELECT StartTime, EndTime, Qty
  FROM @table
 WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,StartTime,EndTime) = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT StartTime, DATEADD(SECOND,-1,DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,0,StartTime)+1,0)), Qty*(CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND,StartTime,DATEADD(SECOND,-1,DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,0,StartTime)+1,0))) AS FLOAT)/CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND,StartTime, EndTime) AS FLOAT))
  FROM @table
 WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,StartTime,EndTime) <> 0
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,0,EndTime),0), EndTime, Qty*(CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND,DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,0,EndTime),0),EndTime) AS FLOAT)/CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND,StartTime, EndTime) AS FLOAT))
  FROM @table
 WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,StartTime,EndTime) <> 0
```